# Java package hell trying to use JavaFX on MacOS + IntelliJ

Tags: java, package-management, maven, 3d

I am trying to develop an app that requires the ability to view/manipulate models in 3D space, for which JavaFX seem like an obvious candidate. If somebody can suggest a better alternative then I would be happy to hear it!

I am using IntelliJ CE 2019.3.3 running on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4, with Java 14, which I understand to be the latest version. Paradoxically, I have a fear that using the latest JDK might be the root of all my problems, given the apparently tortuous history of JavaFX and its relationship with mainstream Java (thank you Oracle).

I downloaded a trivial app that added a few simple shapes to a scene which I managed to get running successfully. I added the JavaFX libs to my project by adding two dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note I am assuming (maybe wrongly) that the JavaFX versioning runs independently of the JDK versioning.**

Unfortunately, the moment I add something even slightly complicated to this program I get the following error:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --add-modules FXTest.base,FXTest.graphics --add-reads FXTest.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads FXTest.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/Joe/Programming/myproj-mvn/target/classes:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.4.2/junit-jupiter-5.4.2.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.4.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.4.2.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.0.0/apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.1.1/opentest4j-1.1.1.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.4.2/junit-platform-commons-1.4.2.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.4.2/junit-jupiter-params-5.4.2.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.4.2/junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.2.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.4.2/junit-platform-engine-1.4.2.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.8/commons-csv-1.8.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-controls/11/FXTest-controls-11.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-controls/11/FXTest-controls-11-mac.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-graphics/11/FXTest-graphics-11.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-graphics/11/FXTest-graphics-11-mac.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-base/11/FXTest-base-11.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-base/11/FXTest-base-11-mac.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.1/log4j-api-2.13.1.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.13.1/log4j-core-2.13.1.jar -p /Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-base/11/FXTest-base-11-mac.jar:/Users/Andy/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/FXTest-graphics/11/FXTest-graphics-11-mac.jar net.foobar.myproj.FXTest
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at FXTest.graphics/com.sun.FXTest.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at FXTest.graphics/com.sun.FXTest.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class FXTest.scene.control.PopupControl (in unnamed module @0x5b464ce8) cannot access class com.sun.FXTest.application.PlatformImpl (in module FXTest.graphics) because module FXTest.graphics does not export com.sun.FXTest.application to unnamed module @0x5b464ce8
    at FXTest.scene.control.PopupControl.<clinit>(PopupControl.java:90)
    at net.foobar.myproj.FXTest.main(FXTest.java:24)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application net.foobar.myproj.FXTest

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was able to overcome this by manually downloading the entire JavaFX library to a new directory and adding the following option to my runtime VM Options:

```
--add-modules
javafx.controls
-p
/Users/Joe/Downloads/openjfx/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
```

Unfortunately, I am finding that I am getting variants of this error when I import a new class into my application, in ways that I find pretty unpredictable (and hard to fix). I am running out of inspiration and patience - and also running out of modules to add to the VM options list.

It also feels decidedly tacky to be using JavaFX libraries in two different locations - my *Downloads* directory and my local *.m2* **Maven** repository.

Can anyone suggest a better solution to my pain - either an alternative 3D package or a better way of managing the JavaFX libraries?

---

**Editing my question to show the progress I've made (wish I could add more details in another way).**

OK, after licking my wounds for a bit I've decided to drink the *Maven* Kool-aid, all the way to the bottom of the cup.

I first created a Maven project, based on the [javafx-archetype-simple](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes/tree/master/javafx-archetype-simple#simple-javafx-maven-archetype). I found this by following the link from the [Maven plugin for JavaFX](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) site. Once I had done this I was able to compile the code using **mvn compile** and then run it using **mvn javafx:run**. Result=success!

Flushed with joy I then decided to import the project into IntelliJ - with mixed results. I had to modify the 'run' configuration, to use the **mvn** plugin (see above) and that part seem to work.

---

Update #2: I have now enhanced my IDE 'run configuration' command to **mvn compile javafx:run** which forces the code to be re-compiled before it runs (if recompilation is necessary - maven is smart like that).

Wish me luck - I'll update this post as I proceed.

Comment: I would install OpenJDK 11 instead of OpenJDK 14 in order to match the version of JavaFX you have installed.  Be sure to update your build environment.

Comment: @SecurityHound why not JavaFX 14 then? Well, I guess 11 is LTS.

Comment: @Kayaman - I suggested `OpenJDK 11` due to the fact the author installed `JavaFX 11` instead of `JavaFX 14`  I would not know where to begin to install `JavaFX 14` on MacOS

Comment: Short response: making the versions match didn't make a difference. Those of a delicate constitution should look away now...

Comment: Those of a delicate constitution should look away now... (dang, how do I enter new lines without ending the comment??). Long answer: I first tried amending the JavaFX version to 14, just by editing the pom.xml. This was a trivial change and seemed to update the libraries, but with no change in the issue. I then reverted to v11 and tried to install Java 11. First using _brew_ = fail, then using _sdkman_=fail; finally, I was able to install sdk11 by downloading the dmg from the Oracle site. However, after switching IntelliJ to use this I had no change to the issue. Sob...

Comment: Taking an alternative tack, can I: a) Tell Maven to put its downloads in a specific directory (e.g. within m project); and b) Tell maven to flatten the jars into a single directtory, which is what the package framework expects? That way, at least, I could use a consistent set of libraries and keep it all within the scope of my project.

Comment: Is there any way I can provide more detailed responses, other than adding more comments? These are severely limited in length and do not permit formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar difficulties when trying to use `--add-modules` parameter.

So instead I created this file:

```
src/module-info.java
```

With content below:

```
module MyProject{
    requires javafx.controls;
}
```

You can find a full working example here: https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2016/04/26/a-javafx-helloworld-using-java-9s-project-jigsaw-in-60-seconds/